# wtforms FlaskForm/ModelForm not populating data into form nor persisting data

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, wtforms, flask-wtforms

When I click the button SelectUser the form does not populate properly with the data from my database nor does it persist the data entered into the form. I assume it has to do with my declaration in my class:

```
class AllUsersForm(FlaskForm, ModelForm):
```

Is there a better way to incorporate these 2 different types of form generators?

views.py

```
@app.route('/manpower_edit_users', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def manpower_edit_users():
    form=AllUsersForm()
    if request.method=='POST':
        if request.form['submit']=='SelectUser':
            print("SelectUser")
            data=User.query.get(request.form['user_list'])
            forms=EditUsersForm(obj=data)
            flash("SelectUser")
        elif request.form['submit']=='Update' and form.validate():
            u=User()
            u.username=form.username.data
            u.email=form.email.data
            db.session.add(u)
            #db.session.commit()
            #rebuild forms
            #data=User.query.get(request.form['user_list'])
            #forms=EditUsersForm(obj=data)
            flash("User Updated, maybe not")
    return render_template('manpower_edit_users.html',title='Manpower Edit User', form=form)
```

forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms_alchemy import ModelForm

class AllUsersForm(FlaskForm, ModelForm):
    user_list = QuerySelectField('Choose User', query_factory=lambda: User.query.order_by('username'),
        allow_blank=False)

    class Meta:
        model=User
        exclude=['password_hash']
```

models.py

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(32), index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
    #mobilitys = db.relationship('Mobility', backref='username', lazy='dynamic')
    about_me = db.Column(db.String(140))
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    followed = db.relationship('User',

    def __repr__(self):  # pragma: no cover
        return '<user> %r' % (self.username)
```

manpower_edit_users.html

```
<!-- extend base layout -->
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
    <h1>{{ _('Welcome to Manpower, %(username)s!', username=g.user.username) }}</h1>
    {% include 'flash.html' %}
    <div class="well">
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <div class="control-group">
                {{ render_field(form.user_list) }}
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="SelectUser">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">

        </form>
    </div>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" width="100%" style="background color:white">
    {% for attr, value in form._fields.iteritems() %}
        <tr>
            <th>{{ attr }}</th>
            <td>{{ value }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table> 
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: How is it proving difficult? No data persisted or errors raised? Checking that submit equals *Update*, but adding a new `User` seems odd. Did you mean to update an existing user instead of adding a new one?

Comment: I edited the question because I merged FlaskForm with ModelForm. The issue is no data persists in my form now. Is there a trick to fix this?